# how to scroll down chat textbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to scroll down the textbox in asp.net using c#? this textbox is a chat box...it should scroll down as the new text comes in. help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want it to scroll on page load then put this in your onload eventHandler.  If your div is being populated via AJAX then put this after the code that is appending content.

```
var sd = document.getElementById("#someDiv");
sd.scrollTop = sd.scrollHeight;
```